# What is the least liquid way to keep money?

Tags: security, liquidity

I'm trying to keep my money safe from hackers and don't want them getting easy access. Keeping it in a checking account seems like the worst idea since it's too easy for them to just move the money around because it's right there in cash.

I've been looking into the least liquid ways to keep my money, and I think I've found that mutual funds are the way to go, something like Vanguard's VOO. My thinking is, even if a hacker tries to sell off the mutual fund, they can't get the money right away because of the two-day wait to settle. So, I'd have some time to lock down my account. Am I on the right track here, or is there a better way to keep my money where it's not so easy to move?

Comment: You should probably be looking for the most secure way to keep your money.  The speed with which you can defrauded is only one aspect of security.  You should also be considering the erosion in your funds due to inflation and how to prevent that...

Comment: Is there any way to put a 7 day withdrawal hold or something. I looked everywhere, no one offers it. It’s ridiculous that no big institution offers delayed withdrawal lock

Comment: Assume you use your proposed plan. Would you really check your Vanguard account daily, in order to detect a hack? Security without usability is not security.

Comment: If you've been hacked, what makes you think you'll be able to stop a transfer that the hackers have initiated from your account?

Comment: Do you have any example where money from a checking account was moved because someone was hacked? I am not talking about someone who was giving away details or login credentials. This sounds quite paranoid to me.

Comment: A piece of fine art or a very rare car can be quite illiquid. Real estate is pretty illiquid too.  A liquid asset stored in a safe-deposit box is very safe. Many other things far less liquid than mutual funds.

Comment: You probably underestimate the attack surface: even if you store your money in mutual funds, unauthorized actors could likely transfer the securities "in-kind," meaning they don't have to liquidate them first. And what if a hacker is able to bypass you "locking down" your account?

I think the question under the question is: "How do I prevent financial loss due to unauthorized account activity?" 

To that, most large brokerages have a [security guarantee that protects you against fraud](https://www.fidelity.com/security/customer-protection-guarantee), and tips for securing your account.

Comment: Another “you’re asking the wrong question” comment.  Good financial practices (don’t fall for social engineering tricks, run AV software, use 2 factor authentication at a Big Bank — I’m really happy with Chase— which gets regular security audits, pay as much as possible with CREDIT card, use an iPhone, don’t install sketchy apps, etc) will keep you secure AND functional.

Comment: There are plenty of perfectly good reasons you might choose to put your money in index mutual funds, but this reason is a new one for me. If you are concerned about security (as we all should be) then the best place to put your efforts is take the time to learn everything you can about good security practices.

Comment: I think the index funds idea is a mis-phrased version of "you don't have to keep all your money in the account you tell others about". What the reserved account actually is doesn't matter for this set of goals. Definitely agree that this was an X/Y question, asking about a specific possible solution rather than asking about the actual goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way to keep your money from hackers is to make it totally inaccessible, so cash is your only option. Everything else strikes a balance between ease of use for you and ease of access to outside parties.

To be fair, if you have the suggested security measures in place (long random passwords, 2fA, etc.) *and* you never give out your account info, the chance of a targeted hack is extremely low.

Comment: Safe _from hackers_, yes — but probably worth highlighting how much easier that makes it for physical-world thieves and other wrong'uns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about hackers accessing your account, put two factor authentication on all of them.  It is one of the best ways to defeat penetration attacks.

It is just as easy to login to Vanguard, Fidelity, or whatever and move money.

Another option is to put cash in a safety deposit box or home safe.